# How can I start and stop the text animation loop from iTyped?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

I am using React, MUI, and [iTyped](https://github.com/luisvinicius167/ityped)

I have an animation that backspaces some text, and types the next word in the array out. Eventually it get's to the end of the animation where the last word of the array is displayed. I would like to be able to click on the div containing this animation to once again start up the animation.

```
 const typedCaller = () => {
    init(textRef.current, {
      showCursor: false,
      backDelay: 1500,
      loop: false,
      strings: ['Developer', 'Trainer', 'Administrator']
    })
  }

  const typedCaller2 = () => {
    init(textRef.current, {
      showCursor: false,
      backDelay: 1500,
      loop: false,
      strings: ['Developer', 'Trainer', 'Administrator']
    })
  }


  const textRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    typedCaller();
  },[])

return(
<Description className='SubText' onClick={typedCaller}>
    {description1} <span ref={textRef}></span>
</Description></Box>
)
```

What happens is at the end of the animation I have text that sais 'Administrator'. When I click on this, 'Developer' starts getting typed out in front of it. The entire thing then gets backspaced, and only a single instance of 'Trainer' get's typed, and so on before the animation ends.

Pretty much I need to backspace the leftover text from the first animation onClick, or I need a way to toggle the `loop: false/true` property so as to start and stop the animation. Anyhelp is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'll just leave as answer to my own question that a solution that works is to first delete the previous animation, and then print out a new one:

```
const typedCaller2 = () => {
    init(textRef.current, {
      showCursor: false,
      loop: false,
      startDelay: 1,
      backDelay: 1,
      strings: [' ', ' ']
    })
  }
```

still don't know if there's a way to do it by toggling the loop status of the first animation